# Input tag doesn't seem to work with ng-model when used inside template of custom directive

Tags: angularjs, html, dom, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I am trying to add a custom directive dynamically from the controller. For adding the directive I have done the following thing.

```
app.controller("someCtrl",["$scope","$compile",function($scope,$compile) {
      $scope.create = function() {
            angular.element(#idx).append($compile("<custom-directive></custom-directive>)($scope));
      }
}]);
```

template of custom directive is as follows:-

```
<div>
   <input type = "text" ng-model="search"/>
       <div ng-repeat = items in itemContainer | filter:search>
            <!--doing something-->
       </div>
</div>
```

The above is just a simplified sample for demonstration purpose only.

So it is successfully adding the directive in DOM and performing all the functionality inside ng-repeat but i am not able to type anything in the textbox and thus not able to filter results by user input.

Please help me to solve this problem. I am still learning concepts of AngularJS so it could also be a naive mistake.

**EDIT** I have also tried adding

```
<input type = "text" ng-model ="search"/>
```

inside the template by doing that i am able to type in input box but that is not filtering results for "search" in ng-repeat.